# $.each is puting the results from loop out of the <table>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

im doing an ajax call and getting alot of results from DB and then im using jquery to loop them and do a simple table. The problem is that the loop is puting the results outside the `<table>` and outside `<tbody>` and is creating a tbody in the top of everything. I know the current results are static its just for testing and i know JS is synchronous, so i cant understand whats the problem.
My code:

```
$('#' + id).append('' +
   '<table class="documents_table">'+
   '<tbody">'+
       '<tr>'+
           '<th>number</th>'+
           '<th>Date</th>'+
           '<th> Cód</th>'+
           '<th> Terce</th>'+
       '</tr>'
);
$.each(data.responseJSON, function (index, value) {
   $('#' + id).append('' +
       '<tr">'+
           '<td>1</td>'+
           '<td>12/98/2021</td>'+
           '<td>1212</td>'+
           '<td>test it</td>'+
       '</tr>'
   );
}).$('#' + id).append(''+
   '</tbody>'+
   '</table>'
);
```

how is the current output:

```
<tbody"></tbody">
<table class="documents_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>number</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th> Cód</th>
      <th> Terce</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>12/98/2021</td>
  <td>1212</td>
  <td>test it</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>12/98/2021</td>
  <td>1212</td>
  <td>test it</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>12/98/2021</td>
  <td>1212</td>
  <td>test it</td>
</tr>
.........
```

Comment: Replace '<tr"> with '<tr>.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+append+rows+to+table+not+working) of [How do I force jQuery append to NOT automatically close a tag?](/q/12948853/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon I'm not surprised there's a duplicate.  Knowing the problem (*jquery automatically closing tag*) would certainly have helped OP with searching.  I doubt OP would have searched for "rows not adding" as that's not their primary issue (though the cause is the same, so yes, an existing answer, but a different question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is jquery is "*being helpful*"(tm).

When you append `<table>` it "helpfully" closes the tag for you, so actually outputs `<table></table>`.

Build your entire table with a single string then have a single .append at the end

```
var html = 
   '<table class="documents_table">'+
   '<tbody">'+
       '<tr>'+
           '<th>number</th>'+
           '<th>Date</th>'+
           '<th> Cód</th>'+
           '<th> Terce</th>'+
       '</tr>';

$.each(data.responseJSON, function (index, value) {
   html +=
       '<tr>'+
           '<td>1</td>'+
           '<td>12/98/2021</td>'+
           '<td>1212</td>'+
           '<td>test it</td>'+
       '</tr>';
}).

html += 
   '</tbody>'+
   '</table>';

$('#' + id).append(html);
```

Comment: You copied the same typo, so its not a table element and wont be added.

Comment: @Grumpy good spot, will fix it - but that's not really the issue of the question.  Also, it still works in at least one browser:  https://jsfiddle.net/4kLpunft/

Comment: damn man i was going crazy! Thanks alot it works just fine, and the most ''stupid'' thing is that i have done it before like you said. Dumb me, i guess its too many hours coding already! Thanks alot, life saver!

Comment: @ freedomn-m You are partially right, yes the table will be generated with the closing tag, but the typo wont allow you to add the row, without the typo, the rows will be added. With append you can always ad rows to tables.

Comment: @Grumpy I'm confused by which bit you're saying won't work.  `$("tbody").append('<tr"><td>ok</td></tr>')` works as does a full table string.   https://jsfiddle.net/qwaL4to1/  *"won't allow you to add the row"*, but it does fine.  Check the fiddle :)

Comment: @freedomn-m You are right, i was thinking adding the rows to the table, but its adding it to the div container. My bad.